# How to pull one pattern out of a text file before my foreach loop in powershell

Tags: powershell, select, foreach-loop-container

I am looking to grab the line with the word hostname out of a file. The files I am searching thru are logs from different network switches. I want to pull the host name out of each log, then I want to return each port name, and crc error for the port.

Here is the code and the log sample is below the code. I bolded the lines out i am pulling out of the log files.

```
# This pulls the port numbers out of each file
[string[]]$port_counter = Select-String -Path C:\Users\tlyle\OneDrive\Documents\Log\*.txt -Pattern 'is up', 'is down'

 # this pulls the crc errors out of each file
[string[]]$crc_logs = Select-String -Path C:\Users\tlyle\OneDrive\Documents\Log\*.txt -Pattern 'crc'  

# Below I combine the arrays and print them out
$MaxLen = [Math]::Max($port_counter.Length, $crc_logs.Length)

$Result = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $MaxLen; $i++) { 
$Result += $port_counter[$i]
$Result += $crc_logs[$i]
}

$Result
```

This currently pulls this for me.

:GigabitEthernet1/1/1 is up, line protocol is up

:0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 ignored

:GigabitEthernet1/1/2 is up, line protocol is up

0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 ignored

then repeats for each file in the folder.

Here is what the input file looks like - Each file has 48 ports -  GigabitEthernet1/1/1 to 1/1/48  - I pull ***2 lines*** out for **each port in the file**- In bold below - and do this ***for each file in the directory***.. I want to pull the first line of the file and return it before the port and crc information -- For each file-- this will show the host name first then the ports and crc errors then go to the next file and show the host-name once, then ports, and crc errors. .

### Results of command "sh interfaces" sent to host "10.16.156.76":

**GigabitEthernet1/1/1 is up, line protocol is up**
  Port up for 490 day(s) 3 hour(s) 48 minute(s) 56 second(s)
  Hardware is GigabitEthernet, address is 609c.9f77.2d44 (bia 609c.9f77.2d44)
  Configured speed auto, actual 1Gbit, configured duplex fdx, actual fdx
  Configured mdi mode AUTO, actual MDI
  EEE Feature Disabled
  Member of L2 VLAN ID 281, port is untagged, port state is FORWARDING
  BPDU guard is Enabled, ROOT protect is Disabled, Designated protect is Disabled
  Link Error Dampening is Enabled
  STP configured to ON, priority is level0, mac-learning is enabled
  Loop Detection is ENABLED
  Flow Control is config enabled, oper enabled, negotiation disabled
  Mirror disabled, Monitor disabled
  Mac-notification is disabled
  Not member of any active trunks
  Not member of any configured trunks
  Port name is dev-wap
  IPG MII 0 bits-time, IPG GMII 0 bits-time
  MTU 10200 bytes
  300 second input rate: 21600 bits/sec, 13 packets/sec, 0.00% utilization
  300 second output rate: 126592 bits/sec, 17 packets/sec, 0.01% utilization
  1078349 packets input, 213724458 bytes, 0 no buffer
  Received 0 broadcasts, 3719 multicasts, 1074630 unicasts
  **0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 ignored**
  0 runts, 0 giants
  1884404 packets output, 2300283173 bytes, 0 underruns
  Transmitted 85 broadcasts, 138932 multicasts, 1745387 unicasts
  0 output errors, 0 collisions
  Relay Agent Information option: Disabled

UC Egress queues:
Queue counters    Queued packets    Dropped Packets
         0             1733399                   0
         1                1381                   0
         2                  14                   0
         3                6245                   0
         4                1194                   0
         5                   7                   0
         6                 105                   0
         7               58847                   0

MC Egress queues:
Queue counters    Queued packets    Dropped Packets
         0               82570                   0
         1                  25                   0
         2                 595                   0
         3                  23                   0

---

**GigabitEthernet1/1/2 is up, line protocol is up**
  Port up for 473 day(s) 9 hour(s) 17 minute(s) 50 second(s)
  Hardware is GigabitEthernet, address is 609c.9f77.2d45 (bia 609c.9f77.2d45)
  Configured speed auto, actual 1Gbit, configured duplex fdx, actual fdx
  Configured mdi mode AUTO, actual MDIX
  EEE Feature Disabled
  Member of L2 VLAN ID 281, port is untagged, port state is FORWARDING
  BPDU guard is Enabled, ROOT protect is Disabled, Designated protect is Disabled
  Link Error Dampening is Enabled
  STP configured to ON, priority is level0, mac-learning is enabled
  Loop Detection is ENABLED
  Flow Control is config enabled, oper enabled, negotiation disabled
  Mirror disabled, Monitor disabled
  Mac-notification is disabled
  Not member of any active trunks
  Not member of any configured trunks
  Port name is dev-wap
  IPG MII 0 bits-time, IPG GMII 0 bits-time
  MTU 10200 bytes
  300 second input rate: 4704 bits/sec, 2 packets/sec, 0.00% utilization
  300 second output rate: 5320 bits/sec, 3 packets/sec, 0.00% utilization
  170203 packets input, 37873738 bytes, 0 no buffer
  Received 0 broadcasts, 3720 multicasts, 166483 unicasts
  **0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 ignored**
  0 runts, 0 giants
  365548 packets output, 160575794 bytes, 0 underruns
  Transmitted 85 broadcasts, 138931 multicasts, 226532 unicasts
  0 output errors, 0 collisions
  Relay Agent Information option: Disabled

UC Egress queues:
Queue counters    Queued packets    Dropped Packets
         0              220453                   0
         1                  83                   0
         2                   1                   0
         3                 641                   0
         4                 973                   0
         5                3717                   0
         6                  46                   0
         7               56422                   0

MC Egress queues:
Queue counters    Queued packets    Dropped Packets
         0               82569                   0
         1                  25                   0
         2                 595                   0
         3                  23                   0

---

***HERE IS WHAT I WANT THE END RESULT TO BE:***

**host "10.16.156.76"**

:GigabitEthernet1/1/1 is up, line protocol is up
:0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 ignored

:GigabitEthernet1/1/2 is up, line protocol is up
0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 ignored

then repeat for each file in the folder.

Comment: Please consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are way over complicating this.

You should be able to use RegEx matching or Select-String with a RegEx pattern to just grab the two lines with the text you are after.

I just copied your sample log, saved it as a single txt file and just did the below.

Example:

```
# Use RegEx matches to match / select the line that contains the
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\Backup\RouterLog.txt' | 
%{[regex]::Matches($PSItem,'^.*\b(protocol|CRC)\b.*$').Value}

# Use Select-String RegEx to match / select the line that contains the pattern 
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\Backup\RouterLog.txt' | 
Select-String '^.*\b(protocol|CRC)\b.*$'

# Results of both is

GigabitEthernet1/1/1 is up, line protocol is up
0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 ignored
GigabitEthernet1/1/2 is up, line protocol is up
0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 ignored
```

Of course you could just ForLoop individual files as you seem to say you are already doing.

Comment: You are right I was more than over complicating it. I would now like to put these results in a table layout. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. You can use -join on the match to get the two line on one line, but then you need to clean it up to turn that in to a table object or do other manipulate using PSCustomObject for that use case. That is a bit of a challenge since what you post show these files are not properly formatted file. So, normal indexes to parse give a response but not what is needed. I was able to achieve a table-like look, but not a true tabular because of the dataset. Well, at least what I could copy and paste from here.